# JPanel and JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to add a JPanel to my JFrame, thereafter set the JFrame's contentPane to a JDesktopPane so I can create new JInternalFrames and add them to the desktopPane, but the first JPanel is not showing when I do this:

```
JScrollPane newScroll = new JScrollPane(newButtonPanel); //Create new scroll and add the JPanel
newScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
add(newScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Add the scroll containing the JPanel to center
newScroll.setVisible(true);
add(desktopPane);
setContentPane(desktopPane); 
desktopPane.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you add your JScrollPane to the JFrame's **existing** contentPane

```
JScrollPane newScroll = new JScrollPane(newButtonPanel); 
newScroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(16);
add(newScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
newScroll.setVisible(true);
```

And here you add the desktopPane to the existing contentPane and then **replace** that contentPane with the desktopPane.

```
add(desktopPane);  // why do both? both add to contentPane
setContentPane(desktopPane);   // and replace contentPane?
desktopPane.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
```

The behavior you're getting shouldn't surprise you since  you're replacing the contentPane and wondering why components added to it previously aren't seen. Solution: don't do this! If you want to show two components to the contentPane then don't replace it. Instead add each component to a different BorderLayout position since contentPanes use this layout by default. Where to place them will all depend on what GUI structure you're trying to build, something you've not yet told or shown us.

Comment: @Hovecraft_Full_Of_Eels I've updated the post with more code, please look at it

Comment: @Cows42: you're now talking about a completely different problem, which is not quite playing by proper rules of this site as my answer above does explain and solve your original question. If you have a new problem, then ask a new question on this site, but please be sure to have it include a valid [mcve] as code-formatted text and not in a link. Your current code can't be copied, pasted, compiled and run by us just yet.

Comment: @Hovercraft_Full_Of_Eels Thank you! I managed to solve a second problem I had as well :)